# Not able to install appium using npm due to permissions error

Tags: npm, appium, npm-install

I am not able to install appium on my mac due to permissions error.

```
npm install -g appium
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to 
/usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access 
'/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access 
'/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access 
\'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
```

is there a way to install it without using sudo?
I am able to install it like this:

```
sudo npm install -g appium --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

But it causes me issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue.
I manually uninstalled node and npm from my computer.
Then i installed nvm.
After that I installed node using:
nvm install node
After that I was able to install appium